# Google chrome ignored target frame

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a problem with my frame with chrome, That working in Firefox and IE, chrome ignore my frame and open the link in a new tab.

"href="mylink" target="myframe"

Comment: Well, it depends. Iframes are okay in some scenarios, but generally speaking frames have been deprecated from modern web design practices.

Comment: same problem with iframe

Comment: Can you please post more code? Testing your scenario here: http://jsfiddle.net/WcFDY/ I'm not having any issues in Chrome.

Comment: Update: I noticed in my demo, that after clicking the Microsoft link once, for some reason all the links start opening in a new window (I'm not sure why). If we had a little more context it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have some problem, but i have solved that.
i just DELETE some 'search engine' in my browser (like Bing,websearch etc)
And now its work normally